# Error in Google Drive: "You are signed out. Sign back in, then click 'Retry'."

Tags: google-drive, safari

Upon visiting https://drive.google.com/ in Safari 10+, I have been experiencing very weird error message that I could not find a solution to:

> You are not signed in
>
> You are signed out. Sign back in, then click
>   'Retry'.

This did not allow access to my file list and I was forced to use Chrome or Firefox which worked fine.

Searching the error message on the Internet gives no results. I hope to fix that with this Q&A.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Safari, I had enabled:

> Develop -> Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions

which caused the problem. Disabling the checkbox solves the error.